# How can I subset a data frame with a maximum number of columns and minimun number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, multiple-columns, rows

I have test data where columns are ITEMs and rows are the people who take the test.
0 means people answer incorrectly the item, 1 means people answer correctly the item and NaN means person doesn´t have that item in his test. The complete test has 373 Items,  but only 120 random  items has each person in his test.
The problem is: I want to create many subsets selecting many columns (items), maximum posible (doesn´t matter if columns is repeated in different subsets), so that the resultant data frames has at least 30 observations (or more) but without NaN's. I want all columns to be in at least one subset.  Below is an example of my data. Please, help me.
Thanks in advance.
My data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6bisriquff6m1u/item_test.csv?dl=0

```
Observations people-ID    Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5  Item6  Item7 ....
1               abc         0        1      NaN      0       0     NaN       0
2               acb         NaN      0        1    NaN       1       0     NaN
3               bca         NaN      1      NaN      0     NaN       0     NaN
4               bcd         NaN      1        1      0       0       0     NaN
5               cdb         1      NaN        1    NaN       0     NaN       1
6               dbc         0        1        0      0     NaN       0       1
7               abd         1      NaN      NaN      0       1       0       1
8               dba         NaN      1        0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
9               dab         0      NaN        0      0     NaN       0       1
10              ...         ...    ...      ...    ...     ...      ...    ...
```

Comment: Please create a small but reproducible example of your data using `dput`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) link explains that in more detail. Keep only the columns that are required for the question and drop others. Also show us expected output for the data you share. You don't have to share your actual data you can create a fake dataset that is similar to your original dataset but make sure that dataset covers all possible scenarios that are present in your original set so that we don't have a situation where the answer works on the fake dataset but not on real dataset.

Comment: Your life will become much easier if you make your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Here, that would mean trandforming your data to a long format with, for example, columns for `people-ID` (not a good choice for a column name!), `Item` and `Score`.  Once you have a good starting point, the subsequent transformations will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_longer` to convert the table to tidy (aka skinny) format.

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- pivot_longer(df0, 
    cols = -c(Observations, people.ID), 
    names_to = "Questions", 
    values_to = "Outcome", 
    values_drop_na = TRUE)
    df1
# # A tibble: 39 x 4
#    Observations people.ID Questions Outcome
#           <int> <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
#  1            1 abc       Item1           0
#  2            1 abc       Item2           1
#  3            1 abc       Item4           0
#  4            1 abc       Item5           0
#  5            1 abc       Item7           0
#  6            2 acb       Item2           0
#  7            2 acb       Item3           1
#  8            2 acb       Item5           1
#  9            2 acb       Item6           0
# 10            3 bca       Item2           1
# … with 29 more rows
```

You can then aggregate as needed.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Observations, people.ID) %>% 
    summarise(`No. Items` = n(), `No. Correct` = sum(Outcome))
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
# # Groups:   Observations [9]
#   Observations people.ID `No. Items` `No. Correct`
#          <int> <chr>           <int>         <dbl>
# 1            1 abc                 5             1
# 2            2 acb                 4             2
# 3            3 bca                 3             1
# 4            4 bcd                 5             2
# 5            5 cdb                 4             3
# 6            6 dbc                 6             2
# 7            7 abd                 5             3
# 8            8 dba                 2             1
# 9            9 dab                 5             1
```